# Is there a way to change file/folder ownership on a server in Ubuntu/Kali-Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, permissions, filesystems

I accidentally changed file ownership of a folder in Windows 7 and now nobody can edit, copy, view, move it, etc. Not even the administrator account account can change it back.

I tried `icacls` and `takeown` in elevated command prompt in Windows 7 but that didn't work.

`takeown /f \\SERVER\foo\bar\misc\ /a /r /d y`

`/icacls \\SERVER\foo\bar\misc\ /grant administrator:F SYSTEM:F everyone:F`

Then I tried `chown` and `chmod` in Kali/Ubuntu and it keeps saying `No such file or directory found.`

`sudo chown -R root smb://server/foo/bar/misc`

Is there a way Kali-Linux or Ubuntu can override the ownership? Or maybe I'm missing a different way in Windows? The properties tab for the folder doesn't change, its greyed out, in a sense. The folder I need to change is located in a network server. (`\\SERVER\foo\bar\misc`)

Comment: You should try to fix this on the server.

Answer (score 1):

In the local mode, Administrator can change the ownership of any file/folder even he wasn't owner of files:
To take ownership of a file or a folder, follow these steps:

1. Right-click the folder that you want to take ownership of, then click **Properties**.
2. Click the **Security** tab, click **Advanced**, then click the **Owner** tab.
3. Click **Edit**.
   **Note:** If you are prompted for an administrator password or for confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.
4. Click the name of the person that you want to give ownership to.
5. If you want this person to be the owner of files and subfolders in this folder, select the **Replace owner on subcontainers and objects** check box.
6. Click OK.

After that if you don't have appropriate permission:
 1. Right-click the file or folder, then click **Properties**.
 2. Click the **Security** tab.
 3. Under **Group or user names**, click your name to see the permissions that you have.

To open a file, you have to have the Read permission. To change permissions on a file or folder, follow these steps.

Important You must be logged on as an administrator to change permissions on files and folders.

1. Right-click the file or folder, and then click **Properties**.
2. Click the **Security** tab.
3. Under **Group or user names**, click your name to see the permissions that you have.
4. Click **Edit**, click your name, select the check boxes for the permissions that you must have, and then click **OK**.

Comment: Unfortunately I have already tried to change it via the properties window. When I try to change it to `Everyone` or `Administrators` or `SYSTEM`, all it says is `Access is denied` and reverts itself back

Comment: I've changed owner of files, folders many time even I was not the owner of file with the solution mentioned above. ( for example when I connect a new HDD to windows which the owner of existed file is another user not exist on this computer.  )